# Bundling not working when edit in tinymce.js

Tags: tinymce

I added the following code in tinymce.js 
// Process type specific selector

```
if (settings.elements) {
                    each(DOM.select("#" + settings.elements), function (elm) {
                        createEditor(createId(elm), settings, elm);
                    });
                    return;
                }
```

Now, when I run locally with `Debug="True"`, it works fine. But when I set `debug="False"` and run the project, bundling is not done and the changes which I have made in tinymce.js is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Since TinyMCE already comes minified, I solved this just by excluding it from the bundle and loading it separately

Comment: I tried by rename tinymce.js to tinymce.min.js and add reference in bundling. Now, its working fine.

Comment: If you exclude from your bundle, still it will render it. You have to delete tinymce.min.js from folder as well. Otherwise if you add reference of tinymce.min.js  or not in bundling, it will render.